# What is the size of single map tile of mapbox?

Tags: ios, mapbox

I am using mapbox for showing map in my app, I need to include offline map feature also. Since there is a limit in tile size download, so can anyone tell me what is the size of single tile of mapbox map? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to asking "what is the size of an image": tiles range from 5kb to 40kb, depending on a range of factors from the complexity of the image to the compression chosen.